# Querystring passed to Azure Function is not logged by Application Insights

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

We have an Http triggered Azure Function that takes parameters both from the url and the querystring, e.g. url pattern "/customers/{customerid}" and then a parameter "includeorderdata=true" can be added to the querystring. So the incoming url would be https://ourazurefunction/api/customers/12345?includeorderdata=true.

In Application Insights the url part is being logged but we cannot see the querystring anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The default http request auto-collector specifically removes the query string and I don't see any option to include it. [Code reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b243ac087e6efcd75b432cce327fa95eca37eb98/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/Initializers/WebJobsTelemetryInitializer.cs#L154). Here is the open [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2609). Unfortunately nothing much can be done at this moment. As an alternative, you can log [custom telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-data) from your code as an workaround for the time-being (note only for C# or JavaScript based function).

Comment: Custom telemetry is a good option here; for example you could use ILogger.LogInformation to capture a querystring for an HttpTrigger function app request:  log.LogInformation(req.QueryString.Value)